# unknown execution context error - importing Realm to Expo React Native IOS app

Tags: ios, react-native, realm, expo

I'm a beginner with RN, playing around with the expo tabs example and realmDB and Im getting **unknown execution context** error when importing Realm into Expo project and using the [getting started example](https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/) from Realm for IOS

[image]

I have followed the standard procedure from Realm docs

1. `npm install --save realm`
2. `react-native link realm`

but when i add `const Realm = require('realm');` or `import Realm from 'realm';` I get the error

You can see my code and project on [github](https://github.com/dmolesworth/RNExpo) with the error throwing when I add the code to RNExpo/screens/SettingsScreen.js

What is causing this error? Am i meant to import Realm on other files apart from the file i am using realm in?

Comment: Are you running with a debugger? VSCode, Chrome or something?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but No, not running any debugger.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I managed to get in touch with Nikhilesh at Expo who told me that I was unable to use Expo with Realm because

> using Realm involves adding native code [and] to do something like
>   that on expo you need to 'detach' which goes like this
>   https://docs.expo.io/versions/v15.0.0/index.html

He told me they Expo were interested in adding Realm support in the future, but for now it is not possible to use these services in unison.

Comment: Darn it! :) If someone from the future finds this and stuff has changed, can you ping me? :)